# where this "username" came from, self.kwars.get('username')?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

In url parameters I didn't pass username but when I used `self.kwars.get('username)` where did username comes from

In urls.py

```
path('', views.PostList.as_view(), name='all')
```

In views.py

```
class PostList(SelectRelatedMixin, generic.ListView):
model = models.Post
select_related = ('user', 'group')
template_name = 'posts/post_list.html'

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
    print(self.kwargs.get('username'))
    context['user_groups'] = models.Group.objects.filter(members__in=self.kwargs.get('username',''))

    return context
```

I tried to print `self.kwargs.get('username')` but it is printing "None"

but this line `context['user_groups'] = models.Group.objects.filter(members__in=self.kwargs.get('username',''))` is returning Group data

Comment: whats the url format for the postlist view ? you could set it up url(r'^list/(?P<username>[\w]+)$$' or similar so that part of the url becomes the input keyword

Comment: @lostboard I didn't get what you said

Comment: as example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example

Comment: @lostboard My question is I didn't pass any username in url parameter still I got the username so, where this username came from?

Comment: So what url set up for your view? You have NOT provided all the code. and toy said it returned None - as it is not set. self.kwargs.get('username') = None when not there.

Comment: in your url @lostbard

Comment: Does django passes any hidden kwargs, like username of logged In user

Comment: kwargs is a dictionary, when we use `dictionary.get(key)`, in python3 if `key` not in dictionary will return `None` as default value.

Comment: but this line `context['user_groups'] = models.Group.objects.filter(members__in=self.kwargs.get('username',''))` is retuning data

Comment: @pavankumar, See [**`self.kwargs`** (Django Docs)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view)

Comment: @lastbard but this line context['user_groups'] = models.Group.objects.filter(members__in=self.kwargs.get('username','')) is retuning Group model data

Comment: @pavankumar the second parameter to `dict.get` is the value to return when the key (first parameter) is not present in the `dict`. You are passing an empty string as the second parameter here `self.kwargs.get('username','')` and this is being returned because there is no `username` key. Your query is equivalent to `models.Group.objects.filter(members__in='')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self.kwargs` is a python dictionary, when you execute `self.kwargs.get(<key>)` it returns a value from the dictionary if the key exists and `None` otherwise. Since your `self.kwargs` does not contain a `username` entry, it returns None and does not raise an error

E.g.

```
foo = dict()
print(foo.get('bar'))  # Outputs None
```